Installation banner is not showing
I have a problem. I want to develop a PWA (Progressive-Web-App) with React.js. I want to help the user and I want that the users are able to see an installion banner. For now, for IOS is everything working perfectly. But unfortunately for Android it is not working. It is everything white. Thats all.
What could be the problem for this?
App.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import OverviewPage from './pages/Overview';
import InstallBanner from "./components/installation/InstallBanner";
import IosInstallInstructions from "./components/installation/IosInstallInstructions";


function App() {
  const [showInstallInstructions, setShowInstallInstructions] = useState(false);
  const [deferredPrompt, setDeferredPrompt] = useState(null); 
  const [isIosDevice, setIsIosDevice] = useState(false); 

  useEffect(() => {
    const userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
    const isMobile = /Mobi|Android/i.test(userAgent);
    const isIos = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
    const isInPwaMode = ("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone;

    
    if (isIos && !isInPwaMode) {
      setIsIosDevice(true);
      setShowInstallInstructions(true); 
    } else {
      setIsIosDevice(false);
    }

    
    const handleBeforeInstallPrompt = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      setDeferredPrompt(event); /
      setShowInstallInstructions(!isInPwaMode); 
    };

    if (isMobile && !isIos) {
      window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', handleBeforeInstallPrompt);
    }

    return () => {
      if (isMobile && !isIos) {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', handleBeforeInstallPrompt);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  const handleInstallClick = () => {
    if (deferredPrompt) {
      deferredPrompt.prompt(); 
      deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
        if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
          setShowInstallInstructions(false); 
        }
        setDeferredPrompt(null);
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <Router>
   
      {showInstallInstructions ? (
        <InstallInstructionsOrBanner
          deferredPrompt={deferredPrompt}
          handleInstallClick={handleInstallClick}
          isIosDevice={isIosDevice}
        />
      ) : (
        <MainApp />
      )}
    </Router>
  );
}

const MainApp = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<InitialRoute />} />
        <Route path="/overview" element={<OverviewPage />} />
    </>
  );
};

const InstallInstructionsOrBanner = ({ deferredPrompt, handleInstallClick, isIosDevice }) => {
  if (isIosDevice) {
    // Zeige Installationshinweis für iOS
    return <IosInstallInstructions />;
  } else if (deferredPrompt) {
    // Zeige das Android Installationsbanner an
    return <InstallBanner handleInstallClick={handleInstallClick} />;
  }
  return null;
};



export default App;

InstallBanner.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { FaFileAlt } from 'react-icons/fa'; // Importiere das Icon aus react-icons

const InstallBanner = () => {
  const [installPromptEvent, setInstallPromptEvent] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const beforeInstallPromptHandler = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      setInstallPromptEvent(event);
    };

    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', beforeInstallPromptHandler);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', beforeInstallPromptHandler);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleInstallClick = () => {
    if (!installPromptEvent) return;

    installPromptEvent.prompt();

    installPromptEvent.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        setInstallPromptEvent(null);
      }
    });
  };

  if (!installPromptEvent) return null;

  return (
    <div className="install-banner alert alert-primary text-center">
      <h4>Installation</h4>
      <p className="mb-3">Press the button to install:</p>
      <button
        className="btn btn-primary mb-3"
        onClick={handleInstallClick}
      >
        Installieren
      </button>
      <p className="mb-0">oder</p>
      <hr />
      <p>Tap the three-dot menu Settings <FaFileAlt /> at the top right and press Add to start screen.</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default InstallBanner;

service-worker.js
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-globals */
self.importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.1.5/workbox-sw.js');

workbox.setConfig({ debug: false });

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ request }) => request.destination === 'image',
  new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst()
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ request }) => request.destination === 'script' || request.destination === 'style',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate()
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({ request }) => request.destination === 'document',
  new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst()
);


How do you intent for users to initiate install? If it's by the button in InstallBanner.js, that one isn't rendered. Execution is stopped by the if guard if (!installPromptEvent) return null;

Yes, I specifically wrote the class InstallBanner, which provides a button and a text.
How could I solve the problem? Do you have an idea to solve the problem so that InstallBanner is shown?

What @TimR.Jensen tried to tell you is that you have a logical error in your InstallBanner.js that prevents it from working. Your initial installPromptEvent has a value of null, an therefor every if (!installPromptEvent) will be executed because null is coerced into false. And because of that, the if (!installPromptEvent) return null; right before you return the JSX/<div className="install-banner ... is executed as well and the to-be-expected result is a blank page.

@Davi thanks for the hint. I comment out /*if (!installPromptEvent) return null;*/ in
installBanner but still the same

Another thing I see is the first if (isIos && !isInPwaMode) inside the useEffect call in App.js: If the device uses iOS and the app is not installed, setShowInstallInstructions(true); is called. However, if it is not a iOS based device, setShowInstallInstructions is not called. The problematic part here is the && which will never be true for Android (bc it's obviously not iOS). You could remove the whole if-else and instead use setIsIosDevice(isIos); setShowInstallInstructions(!isInPwaMode);. Or do I miss something?

And: You have two times a handleInstallClick function. Inside both, you call .prompt() without an async keywork or a consectuive .then() call, so the Promise returned by .prompt() is lost. IMHO it should be (in App.js, unsure if you really need the same routine in InstallBanner.js) deferredPrompt.prompt().then(choice => if (choice.outcome === 'accepted') { ... }) based on the example from MDN

From first glance it looks like InstallInstructionsorBanner needs to be reworked to include the isMobile variable within it's logic. If everything else is working that should do the trick, if not I would look over the service worker, verify that everything is setup correctly, if you're still having trouble feel free to debug through and give me some feedback and ill get back to you with an answer.
const InstallInstructionsOrBanner = () => {
  const userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
  const isIosDevice = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && 
!window.MSStream;

if (isIosDevice) {
  return <IosInstallInstructions />;
} else {
  return <InstallBanner />;
}
};

you should simply be able to rework the if statement

Thanks for the answer. But if I copy and paste your answer, it is still white.
